# Modelling a endpoint for a REST API that need save data for every request

Tags: rest, webapi

A few time ago I participate from a interview where had a question about REST modelling, and how the best way to implement it. The question was:

> You have an REST API where you expose a method to consult the distance between two point, although you must save each request to this method to expose the request history.

And I was questioned about which HTTP method should be used on this case, for me the logic answer in that moment was the GET method (to execute the both actions). After this the interviewer asked me why, because since we are also storing the request, this endpoint is not idempotent anymore, after that I wasn't able to reply it. Since this stills on my mind, so I decided to verify here and see others opinions about which method should be used for this case (or how many, GET and POST for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You have an REST API where you expose a method to consult the distance between two point, although you must save each request to this method to expose the request history.

How would you do this on the web?  You'd probably have a web page with a form, and that form would have input controls to collect the start and end point.  When you submit the form, the browser would use the data in the controls, as well as the form metadata and standard HTML processing rules to create a request that would be sent to the server.

Technically, you could use POST as the method of the form.  It's completely legal to do that.  BUT, as the semantics of the request are "effectively read only", a better choice would be to use GET.

More precisely, this would mean having a family of similar resources, the representation of which includes information about the two points described in the query string.

That family of similar resources would probably be *implemented* on your origin server as a single operation/route, with a parser extracting the two points from the query string and passing them along to the function as arguments.

> the interviewer asked me why, because since we are also storing the request, this endpoint is not idempotent anymore

This is probably the wrong objection - the semantics of GET requests are *safe* (effectively read only).  So the interview might argue that saving the request history is not read only.  However, this objection is invalid, because the semantic constraints apply to the request message, not the implementation.

For instance, you may have noticed that HTTP servers commonly add an entry to their access log for each request.  Clearly that's not "read only" - but it is merely an implementation detail; the client's request did not say "and also log this".

GET is still fine here, even though the server is writing things down.

One possible objection would be that, if we use GET, then sometimes a cache will return an previous response rather than passing the request all the way through to the origin server to get logged.  Which is GREAT - caches are a big part of the reason that the web can be web scale.

But if you don't want caching, the correct way to handle that is to add metadata to the response to inhibit caching, not to change the HTTP method.

---

Another possibility, which is more consistent with the interviewer's "idempotent" remark, is that they wanted this "request history" to be a resource that the client could edit, and that looking up distances would be a side effect of that editing process.

For instance, we might have some sort of an "itinerary" resource with one or more legs provided by the client.  Each time the client modifies the itinerary (for example, by adding another leg), the distance lookup method is called automatically.

In this kind of a problem, where the client is (logically) editing a resource, the requests are no longer "effectively read only".  So GET is off the table as an option, and we have to look into the other possibilities.

The TL;DR version is that POST would always be acceptable (and this is how we would do it on the web), but you might prefer an API style where the client edits the representation of the resource locally, in which case you would let the client choose between PUT and PATCH.

Comment: First thank you for your time to answer, this is really complete explanation, and now looks more clearly for me. Your explanation was a very good complementation to this doc https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/.